# Usage of a comma in a dedication

Tags: punctuation, commas, dedications

Does the dedication "To my beloved John" need a comma after "beloved"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on how you want the dedication to read. There are two main options:

> To my beloved, John

Here, *beloved* is a noun. This says that John is equivalent to your beloved. A fine point to this is that this implies that you have only one "beloved". If you happen to have multiple beloveds (or multiple Johns -- thank you, Kit), you can use *beloved* as an adjective by saying:

> To my beloved John

This second option used *beloved* as a modifier of John. If you have multiple Johns, this can help differentiate between them. Maybe you have a "beloved John", "tall John", and "carpenter John".

Either option is equally correct; the choice depends on how you feel about John.

Comment: Just don't say "comma" out loud when reading this to an audience unless he was an English teacher.

Comment: "To my beloved John" also works if you have multiple Johns.

Comment: @Kit: Good point -- do you mind if I add that to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be clearer with a complete sentence, but it is an introductory clause, and therefore needs a comma after 'John', but not after 'beloved'. Here, 'beloved' is an adjective, not a noun synonomous with 'John'.

Comment: Dedications aren't complete sentences, though.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it depends on the usage. But, frankly, in a book dedication, if you REALLLLY wanted to say John was your beloved, you would be more likely to say To John, my beloved, rather than To my beloved, John. I mean in the subtle ectoplasm of linguistic nuance, in the second instance, John is almost an afterthought. Like, to my beloved. Oh yeah, his name is John. I broke up with Bob. In any case, when beloved is a noun, that is a much bigger deal, like John is your one and only, as opposed to when it's an adjective. I mean we generally have only one beloved (noun) unless you're really a poser, whereas we can have zillions of beloved (insert noun or proper name here). My beloved cat, my beloved laptop, the list goes on and on. But beloved as noun, that's going to be one person. (Anybody else reminded of Toni Morrison's creepy but awesome book?) And just to sum up, if you're torn between two solutions, try to avoid using a comma in a dedication that short. It's not elegant.